# Solace messages are discarded because queue not found

Tags: solace

Can i configure in solace if associated queue does not exists then message should go to some default queue in solace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to perform such a configuration.

If messages are published to a queue that does not exist on the Message VPN, the messages will be discarded.

You can use the following CLI commands to check the number of messages that are discarded at ingress due to a non-existent queue:

```
solace# show message-spool message-vpn <Message_VPN_Name> stats
solace# show message-spool stats
```

It will be indicated under "Queue Not Found".